# How can the tension force be computed to test if a shape is moving or not?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, equilibrium

[Source](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=35&category=253&page=show_problem&problem=3491)

Given the coordinates of $n$ 3D joints ($1kg$ each) connected by $m$ rods. Assume rods have zero mass and joints with $z=0$ are fixed to the ground while others are free to move, will the shape be move or not? If not, will it be stable?

The totals force at each joint has to be zero for the shape to be stable. the force at each node is

1. weight of the ball which is $1 \times 9.8067$
2. tension force in the rods connecting that node.

How can the tension force be computed?

Comment: What is the system designed like? How are these joints and rods connected? Is there any friction between the ball and the joints?

Comment: Rods cannot be stretched or compressed, and they can never detach from a joint. However, they are free to rotate around the joints in any direction. The joints that lie on the ground are glued in place; all others are free to move. For simplicity, you may ignore the effects of intersections of rods; each rod exerts force only on the 2 joints connected to it. Also, any joint that is in the air will have at least one rod coming out that is not parallel to the ground.

Comment: That is fine. But how is this system of $n$ rods and joints set up? What are you trying to build? You will have to make free-body diagrams and form equations to see how to stabilize the entire system.

Comment: i just want to know in the current configuration will it be stable or not? http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=35&category=253&page=show_problem&problem=3491 this link show the problem i am trying to solve

Comment: [Finally answered on MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743903).

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer that may get you thinking in the right direction.

Three rods connected in a triangle are rigid. 4 our more rods connected in a square or larger polygon are flexible. This is why high voltage power lines are supported by structures built entirely of triangles.

However, triangles are not enough to ensure stability. E.G. Two triangles joined along one edge can open and close like the covers of a book.